# Collaborating remotely on major versions in github

Tags: git, github

I am still relatively new to git, have only used basic features. I have a project on github that is fairly popular that I am in the process of rewriting. I've been offered help from others in the community but I would like to avoid pushing my breaking changes as I do them to the original branch. I can have a local dev branch but that isn't visible to people on github.

What would the best practice be in this scenario? Fork the original repo on github, work on the fork then merge into the original? Effectively using the fork as a branch.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: why not just a topic/dev branch on that same repo?

Comment: Have you seen http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should create your own development branch which can be pushed to github. Forking is great but I think it works best when you have a team of committers and you want to be sure that you are getting code reviews in etc. before merging into master. Since you are the owner of this project, unless you are looking for some of that process, I would suggest creating a feature branch and working off that.

Comment: Ok, so I have a local feature branch already. If i do `git push origin my_feature_branch` that will change origin and break my project for existing users. Is there a way to push a branch to the main github repo without it merging to trunk so that collaborators can pull this branch?

Comment: 'git push origin my_feature_branch' will push your branch to your origin  which is just your remote name. This should be safe since no-one else is working on this branch. 'git push origin master' would push changes from your master branch to remote which could cause issues. 'git push' could also cause problems as it will push all remotely tracked branches with commits. So for example if you have made changes to master that you don't want pushed specify the branch explictly as in: 'git push origin my_feature_branch' not just 'git push'